# How to use grouby and count using laravel ORM?

Tags: mysql, orm, group-by, count, laravel-5.5

I have an address table where there are many fields like city, ward, tole, district, latitude, longitude. I need to count the number of rows for distinct district. For eg I have following database table as show in screenshot:
[image]
I have the rows containing Kathmandu, Bhaktapur and Jhapa as districts. Now I need to get the number of rows containing Kathmandu as district and likewise.
The output should be like this:

```
array( "Kathmandu"=> 4 , "Bhaktapur" => 1 , "Jhapa"=>1 );
```

I found multiple solution to the problem in which DB query is used. But I need it ORM way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregated query

```
$districts = DB::table('address')
             ->select('district', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('district')
             ->pluck('total','district')
             ->all();
```

Comment: @Puru I am not sure for ORM way because ORM aren't used for this type of dataset. You could replace `DB::table('address')` with your Model class name but still you would require query builder.

Comment: Hello M Khalid, It works, I need similar result. But I've been using ORM throughout the project. Is there no way of doing that way? I'm trying to learn ORM in everyway. I'd definitely tick your answer as correct answer if it was orm.